# Change redirectTo value of otherwise object in AngularJS $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I used $routeProvider. As you know that it initializes in config modules before the application runned. But I don't know the user type when initialization. After loading config, application runs and I get the user information in the bootstrapper route (a loading page).

There are 4 user types in my app. And I would like to set different default routes for these different types.

For example;

If the loaded userType is Owner then the default route must be

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/ownerdashboard'
});
```

If the loaded userType is Admin then the default route must be

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/admindashboard'
});
```

The $routeProvider had been configured before and default route had been set. Is it possible to change this value? Or do you have any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: 'otherwise' function is on $routeProvider, not on $route. $route and $routeProvider are different btw.

Answer (score 0):

I solve issues like this using Front-Controller: make otherwise redirection to it and there inside check the configuration and on base of it make the redirection like that:

```
 var PATHS={admin : 'admindashboard', owner : 'ownerdashboard'}
 var role = configService.getRoleOfCurrentUser();
 $location.path(PATHS[role]);
```